# How to timeout and exit, if a sql query takes more than 10 minutes to get the results

Tags: shell-script

I want to execute a select or update query. Sometimes the result is not fetched on time.

As per requirement in different test conditions, I have to fail the tests if I dont get result in 5 minutes or 10 minutes.

Can you please help, how can this be achieved in shell script

Comment: How are you executing the query? If it's as a separate command, using the tool `timeout` may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlcommand &                      # run the SQL command in the background
sqlpid=$!                         # store the PID

sleep $(( 10 * 60 ))              # sleep for 10 mins

kill -0 $sqlpid && kill $sqlpid   # if the process is still running, kill it
```

Comment: Glenn, Thanks a lot for the help. We will try this out and trouble you in case any further help is required